# data that retrieved from firebase is not same with expected

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            myList.clear();
            Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
            try{
                for(DataSnapshot child : children){
                    History_Date history_date = child.getValue(History_Date.class);

                    myList.add(history_date);
                ArrayAdapter<History_Date> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<History_Date>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);
                historyListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

I can retrieved the correct data from firebase in android, but it displayed wrong data in the page. What it shown is com.example.XXXX.XXX@7ae91f2, com.example.XXXX.XXX@7bc91f2. What's wrong with this?

P.s. I am using the fragment for this class, and it has one layout xml file which is only has the ListView.

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding `History_Date` objects to your `ArrayAdapter`

```
myList.add(history_date);
```

According to Docs:

> By default, the array adapter creates a view by calling toString()

So, probably, during `getView()`, Android is trying to get the text via `history_date.toString()` and if you did not override that method, Android will return the text that you mentioned: `com.example.XXXX.XXX@7ae91f2`

**To Fix**

Add following method to your `History_Date` class:

```
public class History_Date {
    ...
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return date;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class History_Date {
String date;

public History_Date(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public History_Date(){

}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}
```

Do you mean this database structure? Sorry I am new to this